# Подсветка кнопок в ActionBar и SearchView

Tags: android, actionbar

Как изменить цвет подсветки кнопок на `ActionBar` и внутри `SearchView` при нажатии? Использую `Support ActionBar`.

Comment: Можно посмотреть [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460865/how-to-highlight-action-bar-item-select-in-android), [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640136/change-actionbar-button-background-color-when-pressed) и прочие связанные вопросы. Равно как и почитать документацию или поискать в Интернете.

Comment: За ссылки спасибо. А где можно почитать  по стилям? я к своему стыду не знаю... В интернете , что нашел не работает ничего, как и по представленным ссылкам. У меня используется слева в actionbar кустомная часть, а справа добавлен searchview из xml разметки меню... может если включен кустомный actionbar тэг "actionBarItemBackground" не работает?
    <item